# I cant get my variables to be recognized, how do I fix this?

Tags: python, tkinter

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import * 
import mysql.connector
from tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk, Image

con = mysql.connector.connect(
                host = "localhost", 
                user = "Ugur K",
                password = "password",
                )
```

here I will create my database which also doesnt create it for some reason

```
curs = con.cursor()
curs.execute("CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS organizer")
curs.execute(""""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `organizer`.`anime` ( `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
`name` VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL , `episodes` INT NOT NULL , `author` VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL ,
`release date` DATE NOT NULL , PRIMARY KEY (`id`)) ENGINE = InnoDB;""")

window = Tk()
anime_label = Label(window, text='grid forget works', bg='white', font=('arial', 12, 'normal'))
animebox = Listbox(window, bg='#F0F8FF', font=('arial', 12, 'normal'), width=0, height=0)
```

so here is where my actual question is. The first function recognizes everything perfectly, but from the next ones on it doesnt. so I tried something different.

```
def animesbutton():
    window.grid_slaves()
    animes.grid_forget()
    manga.grid_forget()
    novels.grid_forget()
    movies.grid_forget()
    global anime_label
    anime_label.grid()
    global animebox
    animebox.grid()
```

as you can see I tried to make them global variables but ofcourse they won't be recognized because the variables are defined under the created functions. But if I would define them above the functions. Than I cant use the buttons function since that is underneath in that case.

```
def mangabutton():
    window.grid_slaves()
    global animes
    animes.grid_forget()
    global manga
    manga.grid_forget()
    global novels 
    novels.grid_forget()
    global movies
    movies.grid_forget()
    global anime_label
    anime_label.grid()
    global animebox
    animebox.grid()

def novelsbutton():
    window.grid_slaves()
    global animes
    animes.grid_forget()
    global manga
    manga.grid_forget()
    global novels 
    novels.grid_forget()
    global movies
    movies.grid_forget()
    global anime_label
    anime_label.grid()
    global animebox
    animebox.grid()

def moviesbutton():
    window.grid_slaves()
    global animes
    animes.grid_forget()
    global manga
    manga.grid_forget()
    global novels 
    novels.grid_forget()
    global movies
    movies.grid_forget()
    global anime_label
    anime_label.grid()
    global animebox
    animebox.grid()

def homebutton():
    animebox.grid_forget()
    anime_label.grid_forget()
    animes.grid(row=1)
    manga.grid(row=2)
    novels.grid(row=3)
    movies.grid(row=4)


window.geometry('700x400')
window.configure(background='white')
window.title('organizer')

img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("images.organizer/gradient.png"))
pic = Label(window, image=img)
pic.size
pic.place(x=0, y=0, relwidth=1, relheight=1)

home = Button(window, text='home', bg='#F0F8FF', font=('arial', 12, 'normal'), command=homebutton)
home.grid()

animes = Button(window, text='animes', bg='#F0F8FF', font=('arial', 12, 'normal'), command=animesbutton)
animes.grid(row=1)

manga = Button(window, text='manga', bg='#F0F8FF', font=('arial', 12, 'normal'), command=mangabutton)
manga.grid(row=2)

novels = Button(window, text='novels', bg='#F0F8FF', font=('arial', 12, 'normal'), command=novelsbutton)
novels.grid(row=3)

movies = Button(window, text='movies', bg='#F0F8FF', font=('arial', 12, 'normal'), command=moviesbutton)
movies.grid(row=4)

window.mainloop()
```

I would very much appreciate help because I really am out of tries!

Comment: How is this related to CSS tag?

Comment: The database isn't being created because you don't call `con.commit()`.